# Database access through odbc driver and excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, openoffice-calc, odbc, openoffice-base

Is it possible to access a database via ODBC and access this in MS Excel or OpenOffice, then exporting the database into a flat file?

The program I am accessing data only allows an ODBC connection in. Not sure what database it is.

Comment: It's possible.  What version of excel?  That will change the instructions.

Comment: It is Excel 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel 2003, click on Data -> Import external Data -> Import Data.

[image]

Click on New Source, ODBC DSN and select choose your ODBC connection

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume Excel 2007 and if it's different we can change the answer here.  I'm also assuming MS SQL Server.

1 - Set up data connection. `Data Tab -> From Other Sources -> From SQL Server`

2 - Enter info into Wizard for SQL conneciton.

Your best bet to export to a flat file is to save your SQL table link to a new worksheet, then save that worksheet as a `CSV` or `.TXT` or whatever format you are after.

Let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: It is Excel 2003

Comment: Can I have specifics on doing this for Excel 2003?

Comment: Not sure what the backend database is, just that i can access it via ODBC.

Comment: @Sathya gave great directions here while I was at lunch!