# How can I make Excel fetch data from a database automatically when I open the spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I want to have an excel spreadsheet, that when it opens will automatically populate from a SQL database, using specific queries. Each Workbook would use a different query (or multiple queries). Ideally when it is opened, the connection properties to SQL could be changed.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course. Here are the basics.

1) Create a connection (once)

- Excel-Data-From Other Sources-SQL Server (this is for Microsoft SQL, but other data sources are available)
- Enter Server credentials, uncheck "Connect to a specific table" if you wish to use various tables or SQL queries later on.
- Finish. It brings you automatically to the step below, but you don't have to repeat that part.

2) Add connection to workbook

- Excel-Data-Existing Connections
- Pick connection you just saved
- Pick a table. If you wish to use a query, pick any table, then on the next screen (Import Data), click Properties, Definition tab, change Command type from Table to SQL and paste your query below.
- Import as Table

3) List and modify connections at anytime

- Excel-Data-Connections
- You can refresh, delete and also access Properties for example to modify the SQL queries without adding a new connection.
- Here in properties you can also set options to refresh automatically and at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an ODBC import, and you'd need to [set up and ODBC data source](http://www.ehow.com/how_4642566_setup-odbc-database-connection.html) and then connect [Excel](http://www.ehow.com/how_7203191_access-odbc-query.html) [using ODBC](https://superuser.com/questions/181425/database-access-through-odbc-driver-and-excel).

I've never done this, so I can't give much advice past these links.